# ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT when trying to access my heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns

I created a sandbox Angular application on Heroku.
The application is available (using the default  https://mysampleapp.herokuapp.com ) and I want to have my domain name pointing to this application.

I followed the custom domain documentation to add a custom sub domain: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains

In my Heroku application settings i can see the added domain :
[www.mydomain.fr](http://www.mydomain.fr)  --> something-somethingelse-1234567890.herokudns.com

Then in my DNS provider, I removed my previous "A" / "CNAME" entries (no need anymore) and I added one :

CNAME /  [www.mydomain.fr](http://www.mydomain.fr). / something-somethingelse-1234567890.herokudns.com.

Using https://zone.vision/#/www.mydomain.fr , I can correctly see the DNS responding:
[image]

When trying to reach my app using the browser and the url [www.mydomain.fr](http://www.mydomain.fr), I am getting an ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT error message.

Do you know what I am missing ?

I am using a single free application on Heroku, without any certificates.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Found the root cause: I needed to enable ACM: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management

Comment: I had the same problem and enabling ACM helped.